# Is runat="server" required for HTML tags which have CSS style built by ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, runatserver

I got this div tag who's background image's being set in the CSS using some method like this..

Inline CSS:-

```
.id0, .mySprite:hover div
    {
        background-image: url(<%=GetImage()%>);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 728px;
        height: 243px;

    }
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="id0"></div>
```

Now do I need to set `runat="server"` in this div tag or not? Coz it's not giving no error but was wondering may be I need to coz the image's path's being fetched from code behind...the image's not appearing in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975148/image-wont-render-on-my-aspx-page-after-adding-master-page-if-not-changed-id-w) user control.

Comment: a CSS file is not `observable` by ASP.NET. Rethink your solution. Why not set the background image for the element from the code-behind? Or hard-code the URL in the CSS.

Comment: @rpm: I did..could u plz check my code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975148/image-wont-render-on-my-aspx-page-after-adding-master-page-if-not-changed-id-w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

- The `"Runat=Server"` is not needed at all. The CSS is loaded/associated on the client (in the brwoser) anyway.
- Sorry, dude, but .CSS files are not evaluated by ASP.NET - so basically, the "url" that the browser gets is `<%=GetImage()%>`, which obviously the browser can not do anything with.

Result: Does not work. *Can* not work.

Comment: how come the value returned by the method's is being shown in the CSS then ?

Comment: changed that in the CSS and have overridden the background-image property in that div as url(<%=GetImage()%>); ...the image path appears in the page source in the div..but cant see image..runat=server's making no diff

Comment: Hold on, is this inline CSS, or an external CSS file?

Comment: Unusual - then naturally my answer is wrong. What IS shown in the generated file then? Obviously there is an error there;)

Comment: nothing is being shownn...no image ...these are the problems I am facing now.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012139/need-help-with-css-how-do-i-get-the-image-to-appear-in-the-background  ...and this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013669/divs-background-images-position-is-not-changing-when-links-are-hovered-over-wh  ... help me? :( just can't make this stupid sprite work..argh

Comment: Try entering the full url. url(images/image.jpg); could just end up in the wrong folder. At least start with /

Answer (score 1):

You are generating the css from server-side code? Or is a simple .css file?
If you have .css file the code: background-image: url(`<%=GetImage()%>`); does not work.

And then, the css rule for div with id id0, you must define it with # not dot (#id0 not .id0)

Comment: id0 is a class..the div's class is set to id0

Comment: @Benny :: just tried that..not working..cant see no image still

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the server to generate the path? The image path should be relative to the css file so if your css is in project/css/style.css and image is in project/images/myimage.jpg use

```
background-image: url(../images/myimage.jpg);
```

Also, use firebug to check what's really being set as the background image. You can also try

```
background-image: url(../images/myimage.jpg) !important;
```

Comment: Could u plz check my code here ?? have made changes...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975148/image-wont-render-on-my-aspx-page-after-adding-master-page-if-not-changed-id-w