# Div's background Image's position is not changing when links are hovered over..whats wrong in the following css?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

CSS and Mark up:-

```
<style type="text/css">
.mySprite { float:left; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; }
.container, .id0, .mySprite div { width: 728px; height: 243px; }
.id0, .mySprite:hover div {
  background-image: url(images/image.jpg); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.container  { position:relative; } 
.id0 { z-index: -2; }
.mySprite div { display: none; z-index: -1; } 
.id0, .mySprite:hover div { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; } 
.id1 div { background-position: 0px 0px; } 
.id2 div { background-position: 0px -245px; } 
.id3 div { background-position: 0px -492px; } 
.id4 div { background-position: 0px -737px; } 
.id5 div { background-position: 0px -980px; } 
</style>
      

<body>
 
    <div>
    <div class="tb" id="lBanner" runat="server">
     <div class="container">
<div class="id0" style = "background-image: url(<%=GetImage()%>);">&nbsp;</div>
<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt1" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <li><a id="a1" href="javascript:void(0);" runat="server">Test here<div id="myDiv1" runat="server">&nbsp;</div></a></li>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li><a id="a2" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <%# Eval("Name").ToString() %></a>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPID" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("PID") %>'></asp:Label><div id="myDiv2" runat="server">&nbsp;</div></li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
```

[edit]

I am setting the class attribute of anchor tags in code behind..thats working fine..I can see the classes correctly set for the anchor tags the way they should be ..like class="id1 mySprite", "id2 mySprite" and so on..

**[edit] @Pekka :: Position property is there in hover rule ..see:-****

.id0, .mySprite:hover div { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; }

**[edit 2]
ok changed**

```
.id1 div { background-position: 0px 0px; } 
.id2 div { background-position: 0px -245px; } 
.id3 div { background-position: 0px -492px; } 
.id4 div { background-position: 0px -737px; } 
.id5 div { background-position: 0px -980px; }
```

to this

```
.id1 div:hover { background-position: 0px 0px; } 
.id2 div:hover { background-position: 0px -245px; } 
.id3 div:hover { background-position: 0px -492px; } 
.id4 div:hover { background-position: 0px -737px; } 
.id5 div:hover { background-position: 0px -980px; }
```

Still the image position doesn't change when links are hovered over..Helppp!!!

Comment: You are not specifying any `background-position` properties in your `:hover` rules - how is this supposed to work?

Comment: Also, nesting block-level elements (div) inside inline elements (a) is a dangerous route to take and will mean your page won't valid in markup terms. You may also get some weird bugs

Comment: @Alex makes a good point. Especially FF tends to behave strangely in that situation

Comment: @pekka :: When the links were not bound inside of repeater the same code was working great..like it would display correct image position n all..dunno whats wrong now..its the same CSS! have just included links inside of repeater now..check this out http://jsfiddle.net/xkRcN/8/  ...its the same css

Comment: @Alex..will correct that but why won't the image position change on hover!? it did when the links weren't inside of repeater

Comment: @Pekka ::Isn't .id0, .mySprite:hover div { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; } doing just that ?? ie specifying  background-position properties in hover ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' am not sure how are you handling the repeater in your code behind, I used this repeater and the background did change while hovering the links:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="mySprite id<%# ((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container,"ItemIndex")) % 6 + 1%>">
        <font color="white"><%#Eval("Name")%></font><div>&nbsp;</div></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

PS: I used the top most "CSS and Mark up" you posted and tested it on IE.