# runat="server" at html Head tag causing c# embedded code blocks not convert to client side code

Tags: c#, html, css, runatserver

When I added `runat="server"` at head tag and some css href with `<%= WebAppInstance %>` value. It turn out the `<%= WebAppInstance %>` is not convert to client-side code. I hope the code below can clarify my question.

C#.Net code:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= WebAppInstance %>/bucket/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
```

HTML code as image shown:

[Html code with highlighted problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ywmb.png)
Could you tell me what is going on? Thank you!

Comment: Please don't give a space after `=`. Change your code to: `<%=WebAppInstance %>`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for helping. I removed all the whitespaces but it turn out the same result. Any clue?

Comment: I have given you a different solution. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly remove the space character after `<%=`. So that you code becomes:

```
<%=WebAppInstance %>
```

Else use the full version:

```
<% Response.Write(WebAppInstance); %>
```

Comment: Second method is not working either. The end result --> <link href="<% Response.Write(WebAppInstance); %>/bucket/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">. Actually if I remove the runat="server" it fixed the problem but I want to know what is the root cause. It can be very dangerous to expose server-side code.

Comment: The javascript is working perfectly. Its just the link element where the c# code black inside href not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider to  add css programatically

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = "~/bucket/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

And head will be look like

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I found the similar answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003032/is-runat-server-required-for-html-tags-which-have-css-style-built-by-asp-net?rq=1 / You can flag my question as duplicate.

Comment: I am glad you find solution for your problem .. have a  good day !